# How to assign letter x points on a line graph with pandas from a file

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0. I imported an Excel file into Jupyter.[This is the code which I used to make a small table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVcOq.png)

I want to make this table into a line graph. With the Students being the points on the x-axis. The x-axis must come from the Excel file.

This is my first time trying out Jupyter and I can't find any websites that help with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the y-axis to be their score and the line to be the letters you can use this

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(df.Students, df[col], label=col)

plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the full script to help you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Demo Chart.csv')
df.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Turtle graphics!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import turtle
from random import choice

colors  = ["red","green","blue","orange","purple","pink","yellow"]

df = pd.read_csv('Demo Chart.csv')
t=turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
t.speed('fastest')
t.up()
for b in df.get_values():
    t.color(choice(colors))
    print(str(b[0]),t.color()[0])
    for i in range(len(b[1:])):
        t.goto((i)*10,b[1:][i]*10)
        t.down()
    t.up()
    t.home()
t.color('black')
t.down()
for i in range(len(b[1:])):
    t.forward(10)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(180)
    t.forward(5)
    t.right(90)
t.home()
t.left(90)
for i in range(1000):
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(5)
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(90)
turtle.mainloop()`
```

EDIT: to be clear: it prints what colors correspond to what letters (students) and opens the turtle window seperately